# /usr/bin/bash: -c: line 20: syntax error near unexpected token `(' while using make command to install sphinxbase

Tags: bash, makefile, cygwin, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

Being grateful for some people on the Internet who helped me at stackexchange(and stackoverflow,sourceforge.....), I finally got to the step "make" when I want to build the cmu sphinxbase from source.

Here are the most recent commands I execute under `sphinxbase` directory (*Windows cygwin*):

```
 - $./autogen.sh  
 - $./configure 
 - $make
```

I got this message:

> /usr/bin/bash: -c: line 20: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>   /usr/bin/bash: -c: line 20: ` (CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd
>   $subdir && C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin/make $local_target) \'
>   make: *** [check-recursive] Error 1

After some information searching, I guess that this is due to the **$PATH** variable issue.
I am not pretty sure if the error raises because of the behavior of **cygwin** or maybe of the **GNU-make**(for win32).
If the system searches for some string containing `usr/bin/`, it might get the wrong route.

Maybe there is something else I haven't noticed, so I welcome any helps or ideas.

Edited:
Please see my [Makefile link here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rhZisK0L3QNbDBbl_xgO6GrCFCw1K2dv/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Your speculations seem unfounded. What exactly is in the `Makefile`? If it's online, please [edit] your question to link to it.

Comment: It seems you are mixing a cygwin build with not cygwin make. Be sure to have a cygwin make

Comment: Do you intend to use make from GnuWin32 or do you intend to be using the Cygwin `make`.  If you're building software for Cygwin it should be the latter.

Comment: @Iguananaut,Both of you and Matzeri are right. After I **apt-cyg install make** in the cygwin, the sphinxbase directory can allow me to make without those errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Iguananaut and Matzeri say in the comment,

> cygwin make is not cygwin build

and

> cygwin make is not GNUwin32 make

I open my cygwin and execute

```
apt-cyg install make
```

And redo the make command under the sphinxbase directory.
It works fine.
(However, we need to install apt-cyg in advance.)

Answer (score 0):

Never use Cygwin for Linux things, it is always broken. Simply install Linux in a virtual machine.

Answer (score -1):

Only a guess: Quote this to:

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin/make"
                 ^^
```

(... or the related symbol)